# How to increase the gcc executable stack size?

Tags: c++, gcc, boost-spirit

I have large Boost/Spirit metaprogram that is blowing gcc's stack when I try to compile it.

How can I increase gcc's stack size, so I can compile this program?

Note: There's no infinite recursion going on, but there is enough incidental recursion to exhaust gcc's stack.

Comment: I'm curious - what are you working on? Having your metaprograms blow the stack on the compiler is quite a feat.

Comment: I'm working on a DSL for real-time event analysis in a distributed rules engine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On Linux, you can expand the stack size in /etc/security/limits.conf.

You can check your current stack size by using

```
$ ulimit -s
8192
```

Then expand the stack to be double than that:

```
youruser    soft    stack    16384
```

And then relog.

This will increase stack size for all executable you're running, not just GCC's.

Comment: If it's a soft-limit, it can be increased without re-logging in by entering ulimit -s <limit>. This only applies for the current shell of course.

Comment: I just used some very big value: `sourav soft stack 2000000`. Then I was unable to launch apps like chromium and falkon and edge browsers on Linux! They were all writing 10 GB to my SSD when I launched them...

Answer (score 2):

I use that in my compiler script:

> CFLAGS += -Wl,--stack,10485760

Answer (score 0):

The stack size can be configured during linking. You should look at details regarding the linker scripts. That will only change the stack size for your single programme.